# Azure function V2 style coding - Http trigger and blob output binding

Tags: python, azure, function, http, blob

I have the following code, which operates flawlessly when initiated locally. I input the URL, and the function executes its task by retrieving the TFL payload from the API and storing the data in blob storage. This process is triggered by accessing the URL http://localhost:7071/api/tfl_blob.

Nevertheless, upon deploying this code to the Azure platform, the deployment proceeds without any error messages, but the function does not appear within the function app. Although I can access the application files, I encounter difficulties in triggering it, and the function is conspicuously absent when I navigate to the function overview page.

What could be the issue and how to resolve it?

Function code:

```
import datetime
import json
import requests
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import uuid

app = func.FunctionApp()


def generate_blob_path():
    current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
    date_str = current_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    unique_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    blob_path = f"bloboutput/{date_str}/{unique_id}.json"
    return blob_path


_blob_path = generate_blob_path()


@app.function_name(name="HttpTflBlobOut")
@app.route(route="tfl_blob")
@app.blob_output(arg_name="blob",
                 path=_blob_path,
                 connection="AzureWebJobsStorage")
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, blob: func.Out[str]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        result = requests.get('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/line/mode/tube/status',
                              headers={"content-type": "application/json", "charset": "utf-8"})

        logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed the API request to TFL')

        since_id = None
        timeline = json.loads(result.text)

        tflLineStatus = []
        for t in timeline:
            if since_id is None:
                since_id = t["id"]

            tflLineStatus.append({
                "linename": t["id"],
                "linestatus": t["lineStatuses"][0]["statusSeverityDescription"],
                "timestamp": t["created"]
            })

        if since_id is None:
            since_id = req.state.since_id

        ans = {
            "state": {
                since_id: since_id
            },
            "schema": {
                "tflLineStatus": {
                    "primary_key": ["linename"]
                }
            },
            "insert": {
                "tflLineStatus": tflLineStatus
            },
            "hasMore": False
        }

        logging.info('Payload is constructed')

        payload = json.dumps(ans, indent=4)
        logging.info('Payload is converted to a string')
        blob.set(payload)

        return func.HttpResponse(f"Function executed successfully", status_code=200)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error: {str(e)}")
        return func.HttpResponse("Internal Server Error", status_code=500)
```

host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": <match with storage account connection string and also set on the az function>,
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~4",
    "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING": "<match with the function config on az>"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {}
}
```

My expectation is that I should be able to invoke the function via an HTTP request, using the following URL format: `https://<function app name>.azurewebsites.net/api/<function name>?code=<function key>` . It should perform similarly to how it does locally. However, I am confronted with an HTTP ERROR 404, indicating that the page cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried your code in my environment. I was able to run the function code and deploy it.***

**Code** :

> ````py
> import datetime
> import json 
> import requests 
> import azure.functions as func 
> import logging 
> import uuid
>
> app = func.FunctionApp()
>
> def generate_blob_path():
>     current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
>     date_str = current_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
>     unique_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
>     blob_path = f"bloboutput/{date_str}/{unique_id}.json"
>     return blob_path
>
> _blob_path = generate_blob_path()
>
> @app.function_name(name="HttpTflBlobOut") @app.route(route="tfl_blob")
> @app.blob_output(arg_name="blob",
>                  path=_blob_path,
>                  connection="AzureWebJobsStorage") def main(req: func.HttpRequest, blob: func.Out[str]) -> func.HttpResponse:
>     try:
>         result = requests.get('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/line/mode/tube/status',
>                               headers={"content-type": "application/json", "charset": "utf-8"})
>
>         logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed the API request to TFL')
>
>         since_id = None
>         timeline = json.loads(result.text)
>
>         tflLineStatus = []
>         for t in timeline:
>             if since_id is None:
>                 since_id = t["id"]
>
>             tflLineStatus.append({
>                 "linename": t["id"],
>                 "linestatus": t["lineStatuses"][0]["statusSeverityDescription"],
>                 "timestamp": t["created"]
>             })
>
>         if since_id is None:
>             since_id = req.state.since_id
>
>         ans = {
>             "state": {
>                 since_id: since_id
>             },
>             "schema": {
>                 "tflLineStatus": {
>                     "primary_key": ["linename"]
>                 }
>             },
>             "insert": {
>                 "tflLineStatus": tflLineStatus
>             },
>             "hasMore": False
>         }
>
>         logging.info('Payload is constructed')
>
>         payload = json.dumps(ans, indent=4)
>         logging.info('Payload is converted to a string')
>         blob.set(payload)
>
>         return func.HttpResponse(f"Function executed successfully", status_code=200)
>     except Exception as e:
>         logging.error(f"Error: {str(e)}")
>         return func.HttpResponse("Internal Server Error", status_code=500) ```
> ````

**local.settings.json** :

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<storage_connec_string>",
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~4",
    "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING": "<applicationInsights_connec_string>"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {}
}
```

**requirements.txt** :

```py
azure-functions
requests
```

**Output** :

The above code runs successfully as below:

[image]

**Output at Browser** :

[image]

**Azure Portal** :

The blob was successfully created in the storage account container as below:

[image]

Follow the below steps to deploy the above code to the function app.

[image]

Select the function app from the list that you want to deploy.

[image]

It deployed successfully as below:

[image]

I was able to see the function in the function app at Azure Portal as below:

[image]

I ran the function code and it executed successfully as below:

[image]

Then, I copied the function output **URL** as below,

[image]

I can see the function output with the **URL** also.

[image]